# How to run angular 7 app on android and ios?

Tags: android, ios, angular, typescript, web

I'm creating an application on `Angular 7`. What should I do to make it work on mobiles properly?

It works fine on the desktop in aot mode, but on android, it loads really slow (about 20 seconds), and on `IOS` it just doesn't work - neither on desktop nor on mobile (MacBook and iPhone X, browsers Safari and Google Chrome last versions).

What should I do to resolve this?

UPD. build --prod improved loading speed on android, and now it loads on `IOS` too:)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the ionic framework. It lets you run different client side web applications on mobile devices. 
[Ionic Framework](https://ionicframework.com/)

Comment: I want to use the app in browser (Chrome or Safari), and not to change too much code in my app

Comment: ionic will also run in the browser

Answer (score 0):

You may have used something which is not supported in IOS browser (Chrome in IOS uses Apple's Webkit, not like Chrome in other OS). You may find something here: [browser-support](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support)

If it still does not work, use browser's devtool for error detail.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see it on monday:)